# JavaScript Date not Parsing Correctly

Tags: javascript, date, express

I am trying to complete [the project](https://curse-arrow.glitch.me/) in freecodecamp.org without using the moment.js:

Here is my work. IT works for all cases except when the date is formated ISO-8601 as in `GET [project url]/api/timestamp/2015-12-25`

```
    app.get("/api/timestamp/:date_string?",function(req,res){
        var date, 
            result = {unix : null, utc: null},
            dateParameter = req.params.date_string;
            console.log("dateParameter:", dateParameter);
        if(dateParameter === ''){
            date = new Date();
            result.unix = date.getTime()*1000;
            result.utc = date.toUTCString();
        }
        else{ 
          try{
            console.log("date_string:", date.dateParameter);
            var dateNumber = parseInt(dateParameter)*1000; // convertion from seconds to milisecond
            date = new Date ( +dateNumber);
            console.log("outer try date:", date.getTime());
          }catch(err){
            try{
              date = new Date(dateParameter + "T00:00:00");
              console.log("inner try date:", date.getTime());
              }catch(err){
                result.unix = null;
                result.utc = "Invalid Date";
                res.json(result);
              }
          }finally{
                console.log("date:", date.getTime());
                result.unix = date.getTime()*1000;
                result.utc = date.toUTCString();
                res.json(result);

              } 

        }
});
```

When I run the code, it gives me `date: NaN`! What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Your `parseInt(dateParameter)` is obviously failing, check that `dateParameter` actually contains a valid integer to parse.

Comment: What is the value of *dateParameter*? It seems to me that if *date* is a valid javascript Date, then `result.unix = date.getTime()*1000;` should be `result.unix = date.getTime() / 1000;`, otherwise you're transposing your dates to sometime around the year 50500 (or about 50,000 years from now).

Answer (score 0):

This is really asking for clarification, it's probably not an answer but might lead you to a resolution.

You have:

```
app.get("/api/timestamp/:date_string?",function(req,res){
    var date, 
        result = {unix : null, utc: null},
        dateParameter = req.params.date_string;
        console.log("dateParameter:", dateParameter);
```

What is the value of *dateParameter* at this point? If it's '2015-12-25' then this block is skipped. But in case it's '':

```
    if(dateParameter === ''){
        date = new Date();
        result.unix = date.getTime()*1000;
```

I think you really want division, not multiplication since UNIX measures time in seconds from the same epoch as ECMAScript does in milliseconds so:

```
        result.unix = date.getTime() / 1000;
        result.utc = date.toUTCString();
    }
```

If *dateParameter* is a string (say '2015-12-25') then at this point *date* is undefined as it hasn't been assigned a value. Trying to call *date.getTime* will throw an error.

Then there is:

```
    else{ 
      try{
        console.log("date_string:", date.dateParameter);
```

You should get a reference error and go to the catch block, since *date* is undefined so can't have a *dateParameter* property. Even if *date* was defined in the previous block and flowed to this block, it would be a Date which also doesn't have a *dateParameter* property but the result will be undefined, not an error.

Using try..catch here is less than optimal (it should rarely, i.e. almost never, be used in javascript). Validate the string properly, there are plenty of questions here on how to do that.

```
        var dateNumber = parseInt(dateParameter)*1000; // convertion from seconds to milisecond
```

Given that *dateParameter* is probably an ISO 8601 string like '2015-12-25', the result of the above is likely 2015000 which resolves to "1970-01-01T00:33:35.000Z".

```
        date = new Date ( +dateNumber);
        console.log("outer try date:", date.getTime());
```

I don't know why you're using try..catch again. Why will the above throw an error? even if *dateNumber* is NaN, the Date constructor will still return a Date object (but with a time value of NaN) so the next  catch should never be reached.

I suggest you refactor your code so that the else block is something like:

```
// Reached here because dateParameter !== ''
} else {

  if (typeof dateParameter == 'string') {

    // Validate the date string here and convert to a Date,
    // there are lots of SO questions and answers about that

    result.unix = date.getTime() / 1000; // UNIX seconds time value
    result.utc = date.toUTCString();

  } else {
    // deal with dateParameter not being a string
  }

  // whatever else needs doing
}
```

#### PS

Given the requirement:

- A date string is valid if can be successfully parsed by new Date(date_string).

which is a very loose requirement, I'd do something like the following (also based on the linked requirements):

```
app.get("/api/timestamp/:date_string?",function(req,res){
  var date, 
      // Default result is error
      result = {error : 'Invalid Date' },
      dateParameter = req.params.date_string;

  // Test dateParameter
  if (typeof dateParameter == 'string') {

    // Test for empty string
    if (dateParameter === '') {
      date = new Date();

    // Test for a time value
    } else if (+dateParameter == dateParameter) {
      date = new Date(+dateParameter);

    // Otherwise treat as parseable string
    } else {
      date = new Date(dateParameter);
    }

    // Deal with getting a valid Date, any other result
    // returns the error condition
    if (!isNaN(date)) {
      result = {unix : date.getTime(),  // returns milliseconds
                utc  : date.getUTCString()};
    }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(result);
});
```

Note that the result of *toUTCString* was implementation dependent until [ECMAScript 2018](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring) became the standard, but most are compliant already and return a string like "Mon, 09 Jul 2018 02:19:24 GMT".